# Android debugging a USB accessory application

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I have custom hardware intended to run as a USB accessory on an android.  How would I debug my application when my phone\tablet must be connected to my PC AND the custom hardware at the same time?

I must be missing something simple!

Answer (score 2):

adb can be configured to be accessed over the network and it performs nearly as well as when accessed over USB - this includes debugging and shell access. For information on how to enable that, see:

[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Or, if you want, there are many applications on the market that automate this - I'm particularly fond of this one:

https://market.android.com/details?id=siir.es.adbWireless